# How to get consecutive averages of the column values based on the condition from another column in the same data frame using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have large data frame in pandas which has two columns Time and Values. I want to calculate consecutive averages for values in column Values based on the condition which is formed from the column Time.
I want to calculate average of the first l values in column Values, then next l values from the same column and so on, till the end of the data frame. The value l is the number of values that go into every average and it is determined by the time difference in column Time. Starting data frame looks like this

```
Time   Values
t1     v1
t2     v2
t3     v3
...    ...
tk     vk
```

For example, average needs to be taken at every 2 seconds and the number of time values inside that time difference will determine the number of values l for which the average will be calculated.
a1 would be the first average of l values, a2 next, and so on.

Second part of the question is the same calculation of averages, but if the number l is known in advance. I tried this

```
 df['Time'].iloc[0:l].mean()
```

which works for the first l values.

In addition, I would need to store the average values in another data frame with columns Time and Averages for plotting using matplotlib.

How can I use pandas to achieve my goal?

I have tried the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [1595006371.756430732,1595006372.502789381 ,1595006373.784446912 ,1595006375.476658051], 'Values': [4,5,6,10]},index=list('abcd'))
```

I get

```
   Time                     Values
a  1595006371.756430732       4   
b  1595006372.502789381       5  
c  1595006373.784446912       6   
d  1595006375.476658051      10
```

Time is in the format seconds.milliseconds.

If I expect to have the same number of values in every 2 seconds till the end of the data frame, I can use the following loop to calculate value of l:

```
s=1
l=0
while df['Time'][s] - df['Time'][0] <= 2:
    s+=1
    l+=1
```

Could this be done differently, without the loop?
How can I do this if number l is not expected to be the same inside each averaging interval?

For the given l, I want to calculate average values of l elements in another column, for example column Values, and to populate column Averages of data frame df1 with these values.
I tried with the following code

```
p=0
df1=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Time','Averages']
for w in range (0, len(df)-1,2):
    df1['Averages'][p]=df['Values'].iloc[w:w+2].mean()
    p=p+1
```

Is there any other way to calculate these averages?

To clarify a bit more.
I have two columns Time and Values. I want to determine how many consecutive values from the column Values should be averaged at one point. I do that by determining this number l from the column Time by calculating how many rows are inside the time difference of 2 seconds. When I determined that value, for example 2, then I average first two values from the column Values, and then next 2, and so on till the end of the data frame. At the end, I store this value in the separate column of another data frame.

I would appreciate your assistance.

Comment: It would be good to test the code if you could create a minimum reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

You talk about Time and Value and then groups of consecutive rows.

If you want to group by consecutive rows and get the mean of the *Time* and *Value* this does it for you.   You really need to show by example what you are really trying to achieve.

```
d = list(pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2020,7,1), dt.datetime(2020,7,2), freq="15min"))
df = pd.DataFrame({"Time":d, 
      "Value":[round(random.uniform(0, 1),6) for x in d]})

df

n = 5
df.assign(grp=df.index//5).groupby("grp").agg({"Time":lambda s: s.mean(),"Value":"mean"})
```

Comment: In my question, df.dtypes shows float64 for the Time column. How can I use float64 values inside dt.datetime?

Comment: I tried the last line for n=2:

 df.assign(grp=df.index//2).groupby("grp").agg({"Time":lambda s: s.mean(),"Values":"mean"})

I get an error
 raise TypeError(f"cannot perform {name} with this index type: {typ}")

TypeError: cannot perform __floordiv__ with this index type: Index

Comment: I tried 
df.assign(grp=df.index).groupby("grp").agg({"Time":lambda s: s.mean(),"Values":"mean"}) and this produces no error. However, it calculate averages for indices of the same values. 
In my case, all indices are unique. So, I used 
df.assign(grp=5).groupby("grp").agg({"Time":lambda s: s.mean(),"Values":"mean"}) and 
it showed no errors. Could you explain what is the meaning of grp=5 since the same result is obtained also for other values (grep=4, ..., grp=1)

Comment: `assign(grp=5)` will add a column to df where every row has value 5 as 5 is a constant .... So it's all rows